# How can I ensure my aws certificate is validated when using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to provision a load balancer and a ssl certificate on AWS using terraform. At the moment the certificate validation takes forever. Here is a snippet of it.

```
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [11m20s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [11m30s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [11m40s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [11m50s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m0s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m10s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m20s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m30s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m40s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [12m50s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m0s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m10s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m20s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m30s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m40s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [13m50s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [14m0s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [14m10s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [14m20s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [14m30s elapsed]
module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [14m40s elapsed]
```

This is my main.tf file content

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "myprofile"
  region  = var.region
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "sg" {
  source = "./modules/sg"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_instance" "public_server" {
  ami                         = lookup(var.ami, var.region)
  security_groups             = [module.sg.SG_id]
  subnet_id                   = module.vpc.public_subnet_ids[count.index]
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo 'instance_${count.index + 1}_IP = ${self.public_ip}' > ansible-folder/host-inventory"
  }
  tags = {
    Name : "public_server_${count.index + 1}"
  }
  key_name = aws_key_pair.key-pair.id

  count = 3
}

resource "tls_private_key" "pk" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "key-pair" {
  key_name   = "myKey"
  public_key = tls_private_key.pk.public_key_openssh

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem}' > .aws-key/myKey.pem"
  }
}

module "lb" {
  source                              = "./modules/lb"
  vpc_id                              = module.vpc.vpc_id
  SG_id                               = module.sg.SG_id
  subnets                             = [for subnet in module.vpc.public_subnet_ids : subnet]
  instance_id_1 = aws_instance.public_server[0].id
  instance_id_2 = aws_instance.public_server[1].id
  instance_id_3 = aws_instance.public_server[2].id
}
```

This is the content of my Load balancer module which contains the route53 and certificate resource provisioning code.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target-group" {
  name        = "altschool-lb-target-group"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "instance"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  health_check {
    enabled             = true
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 3
    interval            = 10
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "public-target-attachment1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
  target_id        = var.instance_id_1
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "public-target-attachment2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
  target_id        = var.instance_id_2
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "public-target-attachment3" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
  target_id        = var.instance_id_3
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb" "altschool-lb" {
  name               = "altschool-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [var.SG_id]
  subnets            = var.subnets


  tags = {
    Environment = "altschool-lb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb-http-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.altschool-lb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "hosted-zone" {
  name = "altschoolminiproject.software"

  tags = {
    Environment = "terraform-test"
  }
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "terraform-test" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.hosted-zone.zone_id
  name    = "terraform-test.altschoolminiproject.software"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = aws_lb.altschool-lb.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_lb.altschool-lb.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "alt-cert" {
  domain_name               = "altschoolminiproject.software"
  subject_alternative_names = ["terraform-test.altschoolminiproject.software"]
  validation_method         = "DNS"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "altschool-certificate"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-record" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.alt-cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.hosted-zone.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert-validation" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.alt-cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cert-record : record.fqdn]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb-listener-https" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.alt-cert,
    aws_route53_record.cert-record,
    aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation
  ]
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.altschool-lb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.alt-cert.arn
  ssl_policy         = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb-listener-http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.altschool-lb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}
```

As I write this question, certificate validation has gotten to 20m40s.

Error:

```
| module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation: Still creating... [30m15s elapsed]
│ Error: waiting for ACM Certificate (arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:732887255406:certificate/17f19b6e-3dd2-4234-aea8-56742d1a92da) to be issued: RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Post "acm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": read tcp 192.168.123.111:57898->54.239.25.80:443: read: connection reset by peer
│ 
│ with module.lb.aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert-validation
```

[image: My domain name in route53]

My domain name in route53

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Do you have that domain registered, i.e., does `altschoolminiproject.software` domain exist in Route53?

Comment: Yes it does. It was created by the rout53 resource code

Comment: So you are 100% sure that the domain is registered in that AWS account where you are deploying all the resources?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my route53 to the question, you can kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251611/discussion-between-achebe-peter-and-marko-e).

Comment: There is a difference between domain being registered and you creating a hosted zone in Route53.

Comment: I looked up your domain and it is not registered. You have to purchase the domain name first, and then configure Route53 as your domain's DNS server before the hosted zone will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was register my domain name, and then create a hosted zone with the domain before I ran the Terraform command to build the certificates.